# Как получить размер окна в OpenGL GLUT?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Для правильного отображения обьектов и сохранения их пропорций при изменении окна требуется знать размер окна, как узнать его размер по x и y в OpenGL GLUT?

Comment: [glutGet](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node70.html)